# Accessing in arrays using Twig templating engine

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am able to grab `{{ value.title }}` which displays fine however getting the inner array value it is not showing and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have not used Twig before.

PHP

```
  $product_array = array();

  foreach ($shopifyProducts as $product) {
      $item = array(
          "title" => $product["title"], // product title
          "variants" => array() // for now an empty array, we will fill it in the next step
      );
      foreach($product["variants"] as $variant) {
          $item["variants"][] = array(
              "barcode" => $variant["barcode"], // product barcode
              "sku" => $variant["sku"] // product SKU
          );
      }
      $product_array[] = $item; // now we add the item with all the variants to the array with all the products
  }
```

TWIG

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in remote_data">
          <td>{{ value.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.variants.barcode }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.variants.sku }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.variants }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

If I output `value.variants` it outputs

```
[{"barcode":"5060315468600","sku":"PLU#1"}]
```

But I can't seem to get the barcode and sku to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variants attribute is an array, you should cycle in it, as example:

```
{% for variant in value.variants %}

<td>{{ value.title }}</td>
<td>{{ variant.barcode }}</td>
<td>{{ variant.sku }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

[Here a working example with the sample data provided](http://twigfiddle.com/s3xhy0).

Probably, seen your code, is better you change the structure of your data (you need to display always the product's title) and simplify the twig code, as example I propose you the following:

**PHP**

```
$product_array = array();

foreach ($shopifyProducts as $product) {

    foreach($product["variants"] as $variant) {
        $product_array[] = array(
            'title' => $product["title"], // always display the product title
            "barcode" => $variant["barcode"], // product barcode
            "sku" => $variant["sku"] // product SKU
        );
    }// end foreach
}// end foreach
```

**TWIG**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in remote_data">
          <td>{{ value.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.barcode }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.sku }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```